# In a multi_match query, is it possible to boost a term's relevancy in a similar fashion that it is with field's relevancy?

Tags: elasticsearch

So we know it's possible to boost a **field's relevancy** by using a caret (`^`) followed by a number, like so:

```
{
    "query": {
        "multi_match": {
            "query": "something of value",
            "fields": [ "name^2", "category" ]
        }
    }
}
```

But applying the same logic to the term (`query`) doesn't boost its relevancy:

```
{
    "query": {
        "multi_match": {
            "query": "something^3 of value",
            "fields": [ "name", "category" ]
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to do is boost the first word of the `query`, so hopefully documents having that word at the start of each field in `fields` are prioritized.

I tried something with `span_term` (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-span-term-query.html) but that doesn't support `multi_match`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In short to answer your question: No, it isn't possible in with the multi match query. One way to boost terms is the Query String Query.

**TLDR;**

I think you have a misunderstanding of the multi match query.

You can use the caret to boost fields, not the query itself. See also this [issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/9235).

You can use instead the [Query String Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html)

I create two documents

```
PUT test/_doc/5
{
  "name": "Something Blue Something Borrowed Something New",
  "category": "Comedy"
}
PUT test/_doc/6
{
  "name": "There's Something About Mary",
  "category": "Comedy"
}
```

The search, boost term blue

```
GET test/_search
{
    "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "default_field" : "name",
            "query" : "Something Blue^2"
        }
    }
}
```

The **search** result

```
{
  "took" : 4,
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "max_score" : 1.027436,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "test",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "5",
        "_score" : 1.027436,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "Something Blue Something Borrowed Something New",
          "category" : "Comedy"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "test",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "6",
        "_score" : 0.7590336,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "There's Something About Mary",
          "category" : "Comedy"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

If you ask the explain api

```
GET test/_doc/5/_explain
{
    "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "default_field" : "name",
            "query" : "Something Blue^2"
        }
    }
}
```

The relevant **explain** result

```
{
        "value" : 0.5753642,
        "description" : "weight(name:blue in 0) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
        "details" : [
          {
            "value" : 0.5753642,
            "description" : "score(doc=0,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n), product of:",
            "details" : [
              {
                "value" : 2.0,
                "description" : "boost",
                "details" : [ ]
              },
...
```